# label constraints not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift2

```
class videoCell:UICollectionViewCell
{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpViews()

    }
   let titlelabel : UILabel =
        {
            var label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return label
        }()

    func setUpViews()
    {

        addSubview(titlelabel)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute:.top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute:.left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(20)]", views:titlelabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension UIView
{

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(format:String,views:UIView...)
    {
        var allViews = [String:UIView]()
        for data in 0...views.count-1
        {
            let key = "v\(data)"
            allViews[key] = views[data]
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: allViews))

    }


}
```

My above function **setUpViews()** is not rendering my label on view.Can anyone help me out here. I am not getting any error it compiles fine but no output.

Is there any issue with **addConstraints** method.??

please help thanks.

It works if I add this constraint-:

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views:titlelabel)
```

And comment this line of code-:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute:.left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

But that doesn't pin my view where I need to and how I want it to work .

Comment: I think it's because of the "left constraint" having a constant of `8` and the "right constraint" is having a constant of 0. The left side of your label is 8 points to the right while the right side is at the left side. I'm kinda bad with this though, but this should be the cause. Change the `constant` of the "left constraint" to `-8` and it should show up.

Comment: @Eendje still the same result.

Comment: What if you comment out the "left constraint" and replace it with: `NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok solved it like this-:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 4.0, constant: 8))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbNailImageView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titlelabel, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: 20))
```

But can anyone explain me how this works in detail. This is googled out answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your setUpViews() function in the awakeFromNib() method.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have more views in this method which are working fine.